# Node js игнорирует if

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот, steam, node-modules

Привет, подробно изучал Steam-user, хочу создавать аккаунты, но node игнорирует if.
Код:

```
    if (message == "/newsteam") {
             client.chatMessage(steamID, "Вы уверены что хотите создать аккаунт?");
             console.log("Пользователь: " + steamID," хочет создать аккаунт");
             if (message.indexOf("Да")) {
             client.chatMessage(steamID, "Вы уверены что хотите создать аккаунт?");
             } 
             else if (message.indexOf("Нет")) {
                client.chatMessage(steamID, "Нет, так нет");
             }

            }
```

Вот что я получаю в ответ в Steam:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может ошибка в коде?

Comment: Ваш код не ожидает ввода пользователя. Условие не выполняется, т.к. в переменной `message` нет подстроки `"Да"`. Вам нужно снова запросить ввод пользователя, а уже затем проверить, что он ввел.

Comment: А ещё прочитайте что возвращает indexOf

Comment: @RaulRojas А как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Для того, чтобы разобраться в этой теме, советую почитать официальную документацию NodeJS: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/

Возможно, Вам так же окажется полезной данная статья https://nodeguide.ru/doc/modules-you-should-know/read/

Answer (score 1):

Сначала идет проверка:

```
if (message == "/newsteam")
```

и она срабатывает. Т.е. message по определению уже не содержит "Да" или "Нет".

```
if (message.indexOf("Да"))
```

Затем вы проверяете наличие "Да" в строке "/newsteam", что естественно вернет -1, и условие всегда будет выполняться. Поэтому вы получите вторую строку "Вы уверены что хотите создать аккаунт?"